# Bitbanging I2C with /dev/i2c-%d

Tags: linux, gpio, i2c, smbus

Is it possible to control the data/clock pins of i2c for bitbanging with `/dev/i2c-%d`? if no, What other options are available for controling those pins of i2c that are connected to the machine? I've tried SMBus but according to [SMBus Protocol Summary](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol):

> plain I2C commands can not behandled at all on most pure SMBus
>   adapters

Comment: In my question I've also asked "What other options are available for controling those pins of i2c that are connected to the machine?" (in case the original question is XY question.)

Comment: Linux documentation refers to devices nodes such as `/dev/i2c-0` as an I2C adapter, i.e. it interfaces an I2C bus to the host system.  Hence there is no need for the CPU to bitbang clock & data  to a slave device. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface

Comment: I do need, because SMBus only sends fixed structure as mentioned in [SMBus Protocol Summary](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol), for example: `i2c_smbus_read_byte()` i2c structure is `S Addr Rd [A] [Data] NA P`, Those fixed structures won't help me.